# Archer GRC calculation based on date and value list fields

Tags: rsa-archer-grc

[image: GRC Values]

I have two fields I need to calculate. One is a date field which the initial data is received via a data feed, the other is a radio button field with the values: [] None; [] 6 months; [] 1 year; [] 2 years, [] 3 years; [] Permanent.

I need to calculate the date field + the radio button where I add 181 days for 6 months, 366 for 1 year, 731 days for 2 years, 1096 days for 3 years, and finally show the date December 31, 2099 if the date is Permanent.

```
[Date] + [Radio Button]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, just needed to utilize archers VALUEOF and DATEFORMAT to get the correct calculation:

```
IF ([Radio Button] = VALUEOF([Radio Button],"6 months"), 
    [Date] + "181",
IF ([Radio Button] = VALUEOF([Radio Button],"1 Year"),
    [Date] + "366",
IF ([Radio Button] = VALUEOF([Radio Button],"2 Years"), 
    [Date] + "731",
IF ([Radio Button] = VALUEOF([Radio Button],"3 Years"), 
    [Date] + "1096",
IF ([Radio Button] = VALUEOF([Radio Button],"None"),
    [Date],
IF ([Radio Button] = VALUEOF([Radio Button],"Permanent"),
    DATEFORMAT("12/31/2099", "MMddyyyy")))))))
```